# Diferencia entre self y static en PHP

Tags: php

quería saber cuál es la diferencia entre usar self o static en las clases de PHP. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola tu pregunta tiene que ver con Diseño/Arquitectura/Estructura de dependiendo que estés implementando existen diferentes patrones para acceso a datos.

Comment: te adjunto un ejemplo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fbf56a0adb84a28e1690f489551847a28e70b30